# Is it possible to emit PostgreSQL style type cast in Arel instead of doing it with Ruby in Type::Value descendant?

Tags: rails-activerecord, arel

I would like to use a column of type `regclass` in PostgreSQL database. Apparently Rails does not know this type as I get `unknown OID 2205: failed to recognize type of 'relname'. It will be treated as String.`. Treating as a String is fine for reading, however the problems occur when trying to store stuff back into database.

From what I understand, one typically defines a descendant of Type::Value class to perform casts back and forth. This is somewhat cumbersome with this cast as one usually does `'some_table'::regclass` in SQL. Doing that in Ruby would result in another roundtrip to a database.

Is it possible to make Arel(?) emit such constructs in the final SQL statement? So if I do `Something.find(relname: 'some_table')` it emits `... WHERE "relname" = $1 :: regclass`, that is it uses cast on PostgreSQL side if I supplied an object of type String. Or better yet `WHERE "relname"::text = $1`.

I know I can do `where("relname::text=?", 'some_table')`. However, if I use `#first_or_create!`, I have to explicitly assign this one. I was curious if it could be more seamless.

Answer (score 0):

One potential way of accomplishing this with Arel is to generate a CAST function.

```rb
# Replace `Model` with your ActiveRecord model

def relname_as_text
  Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new(
    'CAST',
    [
      Arel::Nodes::As.new(
        Model.arel_table[:relname],
        Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new('text')
      ),
    ]
  )
end

Model.where(relname_as_text.eq('some_table'))
```

Comment: I'm getting `NoMethodError: undefined method 'relation' for #<Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction:0x00007fffd665dfc8>`. I have `Model.where(...).where(relname_as_text.eq('some_table')).first_or_create! do |m|`.

Comment: What's the output of `Model.where(relname_as_text.eq('some_table')).to_sql`?

Comment: `#to_sql` produces reasonable output and actually it works for searching! However the very error appear only with `#first_or_create` :( Perhaps Arel tries to work out reversal for the function? Is it possible to instruct Arel to autocast String for such column so one can use plain `where(relname: 'some_table')`?